# How to enable npapi plugin by registry or configuration file?

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, npapi

In Chrome version 42.0.2311.90 m, NPAPI support has been disabled by default in Chrome. Is there a way to re-enable it via the registry or configuration file?

[image: Screenshot of enabling NPAPI manually]

Answer (score 0):

Modify /create this REG_SZ (string value) key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\EnabledPlugins\1

With a value of “Java”

[if 1 exists, use 2, etc.]

Unfortunately I can't post images yet, but under EnabledPlugins, you should have a (Default) key.  Add the exceptions like so:

```
Name...........Type..........Data

(Default)......REG_SZ........(value not set)

1..............REG_SZ........Java

2..............REG_SZ........Silverlight

etc...
```

The # for the name doesn't matter as far as what program it is associated with (Silverlight can be 1, Java 2, e.g.)

Comment: Can you give me more details?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Thanks, i have find solution :

Comment: I find way : you can config file : "%AppData%\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State"
tab :  "browser": config :
"browser": {
      "enabled_labs_experiments": [ "enable-npapi", "manual-enhanced-bookmarks" ],
      "hung_plugin_detect_freq": 2000,
      "last_redirect_origin": "",
      "plugin_message_response_timeout": 25000
   },
it's worked!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. It enables NPAPI, the Netscape API which then enables items on the [whitelist](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html). **Note this will only work until September when Chrome disables NPAPI forever.**

1. Create the registry file with this content:

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\EnabledPlugins]
   "1"="npapi"
   "2"="Silverlight"
   ```
2. Run registry file.
3. Reboot